# resolving dependencies of registered instance in Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container, excel-addins

I wonder if it's possible for Castle container to resolve dependency on instance when it is registered as follows:

```
var inst = Globals.Ribbons.TestRibbon;
this.container.Register(
    Component
        .For<TestRibbon>()
        .Instance(inst)
    );
```

long story short, i work on Excel addIn, using Castle.Windsor as IoC Container, where in some point interaction happens betwen custom Ribbon and CustomTaskPane, as Ribbon is instantiated and loaded by Excel, i have no way to register type and then resolve it with dependencies (or there is a way?)

I have two options to workaround, do some manual Property Injection or reference Container from inside of Ribbon, either way it feels awkward.

Is there a way to register instance with Castle container, so that it would automatically resolve dependencies on that instance?

Comment: Are you saying you want to take an object created outside the container and have the container populate any properties that can be resolved via the container?

Comment: yes, although it may sound ridiculous, woud be best if one had full control over Ribbon and CustomTaskPane creation, but as far as I know it's not an option in Excel addins

Comment: See this post: http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2009/11/04/using-windsor-to-inject-dependencies-into-asp-net-mvc-actionfilters.aspx.  I have an extension method on IKernel that sets properties from the container on any existing object.  I think this would work for you (as for the Excel stuff and controlling its creation -- sorry, no clue).

Comment: thanks, it worked fine, although later i accidentaly found http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/23/sharing-a-ribbon-customization-between-office-projects-in-visual-studio-2010-mclean-schofield.aspx so in the end i resolve Ribbon from container and let windsor instantiate it